# Branch of $f(z)=\log(z+4)$ that is analytic at $z=-4+i$ and takes value $\frac{11}{2}\pi i$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let us consider the function $f(z)=\log(z+4)$. We would like to find a branch where $\log(z+4)$ is analytic at $z=-4+i$ and has value $\frac{11}{2}\pi i$ there. Now as i know the definition of $\log z$ that is

$$ \log z = \log|z|+i(\theta+2k\pi) $$

so that

$$ \log(z+4) = \log|z+4|+i(\theta+2k\pi) $$

We want to find the branch of the function that has a value $\frac{11}{2}\pi i$ at $z=-4+i$

$$ \log(-4+i+4)=\log|i|+i(\theta+2k\pi) $$

$$ \log(i)=0+i(\theta +2k\pi) $$

Now after that we are unable to find the branch such that we get the desired value. Is there another method to find the branch of this function?

Comment: Please use MathJax to nicely format math content. I've edited your question for you; you can click the edit button to see how the MathJax input looks.

Comment: THANK YOU @aschepler

Comment: I don't think there is any branch of logarithm that has the value $\frac {11 \pi i} 2$ at $-4+i$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy The logarithm argument is actually $i$, but yes, it's a problem that $\exp \frac{11 \pi i}{2} = -i \neq i$.

Comment: so it does not have a branch ?

Comment: $f$ has branches, but their values at $z=-4+i$ must be of the form $i \pi (\frac{1}{2} + 2 k)$, for integer $k$.

Comment: thank u so much sir.